# How to execute multiple PIG scripts parallely‏?

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

I have multiple PIG Script with and currently I am executing it in sequential manner using command  pig -x mapreduce /path/to/Script/Script1.pig && /path/to/Script/Script2.pig && /path/to/Script/Script3.pig

Now I am looking for executing those scripts in parallel to improve the performance as all are independent of each other. I tried to search for it but not getting exactly.

So is there any way through which I can execute all PIG scripts parallely?

Answer (score 3):

```
#!/bin/bash

pig -x mapreduce /path/to/Script/Script1.pig &
pig -x mapreduce /path/to/Script/Script2.pig &
pig -x mapreduce /path/to/Script/Script3.pig &

wait
echo "Done!"
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use Apache Oozie http://oozie.apache.org/